# How to add small text under a group of columns of an HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

Following is what I want to achieve:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Cell 11  | Cell 12  | Cell 13  |
|          | Small text here - 1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Cell 21  | Cell 22  | Cell 23  |
|          | Small text here - 2 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

How do I add small text that spans multiple columns under the columns? For example, in the above table illustration the text "Small Text here - 1" spans multiple columns(Cell 12 and Cell 13) and appears just below those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to understand that the first row is actually 2 rows and make the first column span over those 2 rows.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Cell 11</td>
    <td>Cell 12</td>
    <td>Cell 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Smal text here - 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Cell 21</td>
    <td>Cell 22</td>
    <td>Cell 23</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Smal text here - 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```